# Que hago con GRID y ROW?

Tags: codeblocks, grid

Estoy intentando usar el `const GRID` y el `const ROW` pero me salen con error

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'ROW'.

Comment: Bienvenida. Sin ver el código no podemos ayudarte.